# Xtify Integration For Dreamweaver Phone app

Tags: push, xtify

I am creating my first native phone application using dreamweaver and phonegap build service, one of the most important features I need is the ability to send push notifications.  That being said I am having a hard time finding a tutorial on integrating xtify with an app built in dreamweaver. any suggestions? All the documentation on xtify assumes I am building the program in phonegap.  First thing you need to understand is that I am not a programmer, I work for a non profirt organization and this is just part of my job here.

Comment: There is documentation on how to integrate Xtify with a pure-iOS app as well. You could find it here -  http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Apple+Push+Notification+Service

Comment: My app is being designed in dreamweaver using phonegap build services so phone gap converts the jquery mobile site to an application that is built for all platforms.

Comment: Ah. Currently there is no documentation to integrate the app into the dreamweaver framework.

Comment: The PhoneGap Build Service does not let you make the proper modifications for enabling push. In order to use push notification services, you'll need to build your app in xCode for iOS and Eclipse for Android, both with our our PhoneGap plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver uses Adobe PhoneGap Build which packages mobile apps in the cloud. They don't support custom phonegap plugins (like Xtify) yet but they are working on it. Details [here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins).

From the website:

> Right now, you cannot submit your own plugins to PhoneGap Build and
>   have them included on our system. We are working on the infrastructure
>   changes to allow this support.